# NLog FileTarget wrapped with BufferingTargetWrapper fails to write log if there is a delay

Tags: c#, asynchronous, threadpool, nlog

I may have stumbled across an issue with NLog, but thought I would check here first for an answer:

To recreate the issue I cloned the NLog source so I could add a delay to cause the problem. Once open in visual studio, I added a console application that references the NLog source projects and makes some very simple log calls. The NLog.config is as follows:

```
<nlog>
  <targets>
    <target name="buffer" type="BufferingWrapper">
      <target name="logfile" type="File" fileName="log.txt"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

All works as expected up to this point. The next step is to insert a delay into the flush logic of the `FileTarget`. (The reason I found this to be the problem is that I was originally working with the `MailTarget` that would hang for a duration whilst connecting to the mail server - I have substituted it for the `FileTarget` here instead to make recreating the problem easier).

Open the FileTarget.cs and locate the `Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)` method. Insert in the first line `Thread.Sleep(5000)` so that the method appears as below:

```
protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    // ... omitted
}
```

Now, compile and re-run. The log is not written.

As far as I can tell, the logic to flush all targets when the process exits uses an asynchronous method call that has a default timeout of 15 seconds which can be found in the LogFactory.cs `Flush()` method - this is obviously not being exceeded.

However, NLog makes use of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` (found in AsyncHelpers.cs) to orchestrate the flushing of each target in parallel. Could this simply boil down to a question of how does this form of method invocation react to a call to `Thread.Sleep()`, or any other form of blocking (such as connecting to a remote server, as in my original problem)?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to enable the internal NLog logging, as described here https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting? Could help locating the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally figured out why nothing is being logged, unfortunately there is not much that can be done about this.

According to the MSDN documentation for [AppDomain.ProcessExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit.aspx), which is the event handled by NLog:

> The total execution time of all ProcessExit event handlers is limited,
>   just as the total execution time of all finalizers is limited at
>   process shutdown. The default is two seconds. An unmanaged host can
>   change this execution time by calling the
>   ICLRPolicyManager::SetTimeout method with the OPR_ProcessExit
>   enumeration value.

So it seems the only way to handle this from managed code, is to manually call `LogManager.Flush()` before allowing the application to exit.