# Nlog doesn't print messages on application close

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, nlog

All ViewModel classes inherit from a base class:

```
public abstract class ScreenBase : ViewModelBase, IScreen, IDisposable
{
  protected readonly NLog.Logger _logger;
  protected ScreenBase()
        : this(Messenger.Default) { }

  protected ScreenBase(IMessenger messenger)
        : base(messenger)
  {
    _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType().Name);
    _logger.Debug("{0} ({1}) constructed. ", this.GetType().Name, this.GetHashCode());
  }

  ~ScreenBase()
  {
    FinalizeProc();
  }

  [Conditional("DEBUG")]
  private void FinalizeProc()
  {
    _logger.Debug("{0} ({1}) Finalized. ", this.GetType().Name, this.GetHashCode());
  }
}
```

As you can see, any time instance of ViewModel is created / destroyed, it should log it. I am logging it into Console window  and file:

```
<targets>
  <!-- add your targets here -->
  <target name="logDebugInfo" xsi:type="File" deleteOldFileOnStartup="true" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=CommonApplicationData}/MyApp/debug.txt" layout="${longdate} | ${uppercase:${level}} | ${stacktrace} | ${message}${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=tostring}}" />
  <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" />
</targets>

<rules>
  <!-- add your logging rules here -->
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" maxlevel="Info" writeTo="logDebugInfo" />
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />   
</rules>
```

Each message is properly logged until the application is closed. When 'X' Close button is pressed on the main view, I do not do anything specific in code, I let the application close itself. However, no 'Finalized' messages are displayed at that point.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finalizer not called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200848/finalizer-not-called)

Comment: It is not duplicate, the finalizer IS called, _logger.Debug(...) is executed, but the output in file/console is not registered.

Comment: Could be related to the answer provided in this post [NLog FileTarget wrapped with BufferingTargetWrapper fails to write log if there is a delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226353/nlog-filetarget-wrapped-with-bufferingtargetwrapper-fails-to-write-log-if-there/15775837#15775837)

Comment: The issue is similar, but your comment on that topic led me to conclusion why is this happening.  After I have enabled InternalLogger, I notices that Logger is destroyed on application shutdown, so the reason why it doesnt log. If you would like to post your answer, just mention something about enabling Internal Logger, or whatever, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is that Logger is being destroyed on application shutdown.