# Properly configure NLogs BufferingWrapper for multiple email targets?

Tags: logging, nlog

I want to email Warnings and Errors to different mail targets.  I have set them up to use BufferingWrapper.

```
  <targets>
      <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="angryMailBuffer" bufferSize="100">
        <target name="angryMail"
                xsi:type="Mail"
                smtpServer="smptserver"
                from="fromemail"
                subject="Error"
                to="toemail" />
      </target>

      <target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" name="warningMailBuffer" bufferSize="500">
        <target name="warningMail"
                xsi:type="Mail"
                smtpServer="smtpserver"
                from="fromemail"
                subject="Warnings"
                to="toemail"/>
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" level="Error" writeTo="angryMailBuffer"/>
      <logger name="*" level="Warn" writeTo="warningMailBuffer"/>
    </rules>
```

and a very simple console app:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Error("error");
    Log.Error("error");
    Log.Warn("warning");
    Log.Warn("warning");
}
```

This results in a single email being sent that contains the warnings.  The errors are not sent.

If I modify the rules to write to the Mail target instead of the buffer.  I get 3 emails.  2 errors, and 1 warning.

Why is NLog not behaving as I would expect?

Comment: That is very interesting, I need to look into that. What version of NLog are you using?

Comment: 3.1.0.0  A colleague suggested I add LogManager.Flush() to the end of the program.  That did result in all the errors/warning being emailed with both target types, BufferingWrapper, and Mail.  Is it just good practice to do that, or is something else maybe going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775837. 
Meaning that there is not much to be done except calling flush manually before the program exits, which is necessary because of the AppDomain.ProcessExit event used.